# Saving tabularx in a box

Tags: boxes, tabularx, expl3

As the title states I want to save a `tabularx` in a box. Usually I would use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228430/124577) to save it in a box and later on typeset it. But the problem is that want to use it in an environment.

So the naive approach which works with `tabular`, but not `tabularx` would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{strange}{}
    {
        \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
        \tabularx{\textwidth}{|l|ll|}
    }
    {
        \endtabularx
        \end{lrbox}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{strange}
x & y & z\\\hline
\end{strange}

\end{document}
```

*Question:* Is it even possible to get a tabularx saved into a box, and if yes, how?

<sub>I'm adding the [expl3](/questions/tagged/expl3) tag here, because this environment will be defined in expl3 context. So any solution with l3box is appreciated too.</sub>

Comment: note that as you are not in expl3 context you are missing a lot of `%` (although that's unrelated to the question here)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, forgot to correct that. So I'll add the explsyntax commands.

Comment: A `strange` environment this is ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{strange}{}
    {%
        \lrbox\mybox
        \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|ll|}%
    }
    {%
        \endtabularx
        \endlrbox
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{strange}
x & y & z\\\hline
\end{strange}


\hrule

\begin{center}
\usebox\mybox
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

`\tabularx` needs to know which environment name will appear in `\end{....}` in the source file, so that it can grab the environment body, if you nest a `\begin{lrbox}` then it wants to see `\end{lrbox}` but that isn't there.

Comment: The `\hrule` is confusing here, in my point of view -- the screen shot indicates that there is a spacing between the upper rule and the real tabular content, not everybody will notice the `\hrule` there

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added it to show that the printed output comes from the usebox (after the rule) rather than (as would happen in some bad implementations) directly at the environment if it failed to save into a box.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; the error was invalid input. Hence you get the tick, because no extra package is needed ;)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `tabularx` you must have no `\begin` in the “start” part of the new environment definition. On the other hand using `\lrbox` instead of `\begin{lrbox}` is not recommended, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125954/4427.

If you're not going to nest `strange` environments, the easiest workaround is with `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewEnviron{strange}[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{|l|ll|}\BODY\end{tabularx}%
  \end{lrbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{strange}
x & y & z\\\hline
\end{strange}

\end{document}
```

You can also call `\begin{strange}[10cm]` (or any other length).

Comment: not recommended in general but OK in special situations if suggested by a trustworthy source, I'm sure you meant to say?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean you're a trustworthy source? Oh, come on! `;-)`